# Solving this in mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I have following code in Mathematica:

```
rbar = 0.006236
rt = r_bar
k = 0.95
sigmar = 0.002
betazr = -0.00014
sigmaz = 0.4
pi = 0.99
chi = 0.05
Cbar = -3.7

alpha1[n_] := alpha1[n] = alpha1[n - 1] + alpha2[n - 1]
alpha2[n_] := alpha2[n] = k (alpha2[n - 1])
sigma1sq[n_] := 
 sigma1sq[n] = sigma2sq[n - 1] + 2 sigma12[n - 1] + sigmaz^2
sigma12[n_] := 
 sigma12[n] = k (sigma12[n - 1]) + k (sigma2sq[n - 1]) + betazr
sigma2sq[n_] := sigma2sq[n] = (k^2) (sigma2sq[n - 1]) + sigmar^2
phi1[n_] := phi1[n] = phi1[n - 1] + phi2[n - 1] + (0.5) (sigmaz^2)
phi2[n_] := phi2[n] = k (phi2[n - 1]) + (1 - k) (rbar)
psi[n_] := psi[n] = phi1[n] - (0.5) (sigma1sq[n])

alpha1[0] = 0
alpha2[0] = 1
sigma1sq[0] = 0
sigma12[0] = 0
sigma2sq[0] = 0
phi1[0] = 0
phi2[0] = 0

B[h_, r_] := Exp[(-alpha1[h]) (r) - psi[h]]
Exp[Cbar - beta] Sum[(Pi^x) B[x, r], {x, 1, 1000}]
```

and I am wondering if it is possible to solve the last line such that I have "r" as a function of "beta", satisfying

```
Exp[Cbar - beta] Sum[(Pi^x) B[x, r], {x, 1, 1000}] == 1
```

Because ultimately, I would need to integrate a function J[r] over "beta", so if I don't have "r" as a function of "beta", I don't know how to do the integration of J[r].

Comment: It would have to have your code reduced a bit. For instance, you could solve all the recursion equations such as `RSolve[{alpha2[n] == k (alpha2[n - 1]), alpha2[0] == 1}, alpha2[n], n][[1, 1, 2]]`.

Comment: what does [1, 1, 2] do in this case? Is it possible to isolate the "r"? Thanks!

Comment: `[[...]]` is the same as `Part`. I used it to extract the solution to `RSolve`, which comes in the form `{{alpha2->solution}}`. I think you can make some progress on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have r as an explicit function of beta, but perhaps you can do some numerical magic. Let's see the form of the function in some selected interval:

```
B[h_, r_] := Exp[(-alpha1[h]) (r) - psi[h]]
g0 = ContourPlot[ 1 == Exp[Cbar - beta] Sum[(Pi^x) B[x, r], {x, 1, 1000}], 
                  {r, 25, 60}, {beta, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's almost straight there.

Let's get those points:

```
ll = FullForm[g0] /. Graphics[GraphicsComplex[x_, ___], ___] -> x;
```

And now fit a straight line

```
line = Fit[ll[[1]], {1, r}, r]
Show[ListPlot[ll[[1]], PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[line, {r, 52.3, 53.5}]]

(* 1085.- 20.5337 r *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, in the interval I selected, you could use

```
beta = 1085 - 20.5337 r
```